# Why can Search results not be removed from mailing recipients?

Tags: search-results, mailing

When doing a contact search and using the action "Send email", a new draft mailing is created and a hidden group is assigned as recipients to the draft mailing. It is is displayed as "Search results" and has a different color.

If I click on the cross to remove it from the recipients, I get a message *"This mailing was generated based on search results. The search results cannot be removed."*. Why is that? I looked at the code where this restriction is enforced, but couldn't see anything that would suggest why search results cannot be deleted.

Comment: Assuming you are on a recent version, please clarify your 'Send email'. There is no such action afaik. You have either "Email - send/schedule via civimail' or 'Email - send now to 50 or less'. Also can you clarify why, if you have done a search to find contacts to then send an email to, you then want to remove those contacts?

Comment: Yes sorry I wrote that out of my memory, I am talking about "Email - send/schedule via civimail". The use case is mainly: the user realizes while composing the email that the search criteria were not correct, and want to re-do the search (We have an extension to associate search results to an existing draft). They may also want to replace the search results by a group they have prepared earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this was an intended outcome ie, you do a search, you find your contacts, you use "Email - send/schedule via civimail" and that locks in the recipients.

If at that point you decide your search was incorrect, then you need to start over.